# How to have min-width and break to next line for contenteditable at same time

Tags: css

I created a text with contenteditable area but I faced a problem : I want contenteditable area to have min width so user will see area even after deleting text in it that's why I used display:inline-block but the contenteditable area does not break to next line it expand only and when I remove display:inline-block the contenteditable area break to next line when reach the end of the line but I can not use min width so if the user delete the text in contenteditable area it just disappear so you need to rreload the page .So how can I have them both ?

```css
span.a{
    
   display:inline-block;
    min-width:20px; 
    border:1px solid black;
   
}
```

```html
 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
   Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, <span  class="a" contenteditable="true" >AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA </span> took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
   It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
   It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
   and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to keep the element inline and consider the `:empty` pseudo class to add some padding when there is not content. Doing so you will be sure the area will always be visible:

```css
span.a {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
span.a:empty {
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, <span class="a" contenteditable="true">AAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAA </span> took a galley of type and scrambled
it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for your help if I have RTL text should I do the padding-right and what's the ddifference between padding-left and padding-right ?

Comment: @ZACK_G there is no difference in this case since you will be dealing with an empty element so adding to the left or the right will be the same ;) you can even add both by doing `padding:0 5px`